# Creating hyperlink for one of the fields in dataframe in Python

Tags: python, html

I want to have a clickable hyperlink on one of the fields where in the first part of the hyperlink is a URL and for the second part I would like to concatenate it with the field value

I tried examples like the one below but it doesnt work:

```
import pandas as pd ; 
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(['http://google.com', 'http://duckduckgo.com'])

def make_clickable(val):
    return '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(val,val)

print(df.style.format(make_clickable))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it doesn't work"?

Comment: When I run the python script. It just comes out of the code. It doesn't display the hyperlinks

Comment: Are you sure that calling it with df.style.format(... is correct syntax, and that this should return a string? I have seen examples with df.styler.format...  and also format_index to specify the value used for it

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate a field value with a URL to make it a clickable hyperlink, modify the make_clickable function as follows:

```
def make_clickable(val):
    url = '<http://example.com/>'
    return '<a href="{}{}">{}</a>'.format(url, val, val)


def make_clickable(val):
    url = 'http://example.com/'
    return f'<a href="{url}{val}">{val}</a>'
```

Then, apply this function to the desired field in the Pandas DataFrame to make it clickable.

Comment: This is just a change from format to use f-strings, but does not solve the problem

Comment: Then go for below 

df['URLs'] = df['URLs'].apply(make_clickable) ///

from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(df.to_html(escape=False))